# Comparing Datagridviews vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have datagridviews both displaying data (each showing a group - 1 and 2), basically both of them are showing parts and slot numbers and a few other bits, part numbers and slots are the main information, the first gridview showing the current parts and a slot numbers where they go, and the second gridview showing the next group they're going to move on to (part numbers and slots). There are commonalities between the groups, so as an example 1111-1111 in slot 1 is shown in the first and second gridview - what i need to try and do is to color the second gridview backgrounds of the similar rows green if it exists in the first one, but if it doesnt exist then color the row red.

I've got all the correct data showing, just need to color the similarities green and the missing ones on the second gridview that arnt in the first group red.

I've tried google but nothings really working and i hope you guys an girls could help.

Below is most of the code for populating the datagridviews.

```
    connect()

    If combo_line.Text = "All" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT v_machine, v_part, v_feedertype, v_slot, v_track FROM [sql_valor_groups] ORDER BY v_machine ASC"
    Else
        If combo_machine.Text = "All" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT v_machine, v_part, v_feedertype, v_slot, v_track FROM [sql_valor_groups] WHERE v_line = '" & combo_line.Text & "' AND v_group = '" & combo_group.Text & "' ORDER BY v_machine ASC"
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT v_machine, v_part, v_feedertype, v_slot, v_track FROM [sql_valor_groups] WHERE v_line = '" & combo_line.Text & "' AND v_group = '" & combo_group2.Text & "' ORDER BY v_machine ASC"
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT v_machine, v_part, v_feedertype, v_slot, v_track FROM [sql_valor_groups] WHERE v_line = '" & combo_line.Text & "' AND v_machine = '" & combo_machine.Text & "' AND v_group = '" & combo_group.Text & "' ORDER BY v_machine ASC"
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT v_machine, v_part, v_feedertype, v_slot, v_track FROM [sql_valor_groups] WHERE v_line = '" & combo_line.Text & "' AND v_machine = '" & combo_machine.Text & "' AND v_group = '" & combo_group2.Text & "' ORDER BY v_machine ASC"
        End If

    End If


    Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    Me.BindingSource.DataSource = table

    DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource

    DataGridView.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Machine:"
    DataGridView.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Part:"
    DataGridView.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Feeder Type:"
    DataGridView.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Slot:"
    DataGridView.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Track:"

    DataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

    DataGridView.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight = 30



    Dim dataAdapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2.CommandText, con2.ConnectionString)
    Dim table2 As New DataTable()
    table2.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter2.Fill(table2)
    Me.BindingSource2.DataSource = table2

    DataGridView2.DataSource = BindingSource2

    DataGridView2.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Machine:"
    DataGridView2.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Part:"
    DataGridView2.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Feeder Type:"
    DataGridView2.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Slot:"
    DataGridView2.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Track:"

    DataGridView2.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

    DataGridView2.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight = 30

    disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your rows from datagridview and match in datagridview2

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView.Rows(i)
        If DataGridView2.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
                If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString() = DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value.ToString() And row.Cells(3).Value.ToString() = DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value.ToString() Then
                    DataGridView2.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
                Else
                    DataGridView2.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```